# application crashes when I move from one fragment to another

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments

I have four fragments in my application. the first one gets GPS data for calculating speed which works fine. as soon as the application gets the gps data and move to other fragments it crashes. FYI, other fragments are all without any code.

here is my MainActivity class:

```js
package ir.helpx.speedx;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar =(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new HomeFragment(), "Home");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new CompassFragment(), "Compass");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new HUDFragment(), "HUD");
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);


    }


    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"GPS permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    //  get Location from your device by some method or code

                } else {
                    // show user that permission was denied. inactive the location based feature or force user to close the app
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and my MainActivity XML:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ir.helpx.speedx.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <include
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
            />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
         ></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is my first Fragment called Home:

```js
package ir.helpx.speedx;


import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener{


    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        LocationManager mgr;
        mgr = (LocationManager)getContext().getSystemService(getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        this.onLocationChanged(null);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }

    //TextView msg1;

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (location==null){
        TextView currentSpeed = null;

        }
        else {
            float nCurrentSpeed = location.getSpeed();
            TextView currentSpeed = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.speed);
            currentSpeed.setText((int)nCurrentSpeed*18/5+"");
            //msg1=currentSpeed;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Location Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

and here is the related XML

```js
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ir.helpx.speedx.HomeFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/speed"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="180sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/speed"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

and here is my second Fragment:

```js
package ir.helpx.speedx;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HUDFragment extends Fragment {


    public HUDFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hud, container, false);
    }

}
```

rest of the fragments are similar to

I have a toolbar XML:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minWidth="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and finally my my ViewPagerAdapter:

```js
package ir.helpx.speedx;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by abe on 5/29/2017.
 */

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tabTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragments(Fragment fragments, String titles){
        this.fragments.add(fragments);
        this.tabTitles.add(titles);
    }


    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

Please HELP me! thank you

Comment: Please provide a 'crash' explanation, what is it, more details.

Comment: the application closes as soon as I go to the third or forth fragment. this happens when the GPS is located. Otherwise (when the GPS is Not located) it works just fine.

Comment: I think I could fix it by adding  -----  viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4); ----  to my MainActivity. I think that was because by default ViewPager retains only one page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Please tell that I did the right thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I could fix it by adding

```js
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```

to my MainActivity. I think that was because by default ViewPager retains only one page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Please tell me if I did the right thing!